# Android notification icon

Tags: android, android-notifications

I need to make a notification icon.

Icon will show just a number.

What size do I need to look nice?

I am thinking of a similar size as here: https://lh5.ggpht.com/4G8a85pukLYnj0Xu5H23ZjqNNYyTJuIGdTVvDqgnqj4i_z8AMp73uo4uGcCss2f6cg

I do every icon looks ugly number. The edges are ragged

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the official Android guidelines [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html). You're looking for *Status Bar* Icons:

```
LDPI:  18 x 18 px    
MDPI:  24 x 24 px   
HDPI:  36 x 36 px    
XHDPI: 48 x 48 px
```

Comment: Doing so. But it looks terribly ugly. The font is "torn". What font is best to use.

Comment: But be careful! When the user pulls down the notification bar, the icon gets stretched on newer android systems (4.0+ i think)

Comment: How do I deal with this? After all, the application must run on each.

Comment: The images will be scaled down by the system, if you load them into the notification bar as icon. When i messed around with something similar, i made really big drawables (around 100x100), and they looked good. However, this will increase the size of your apk, and possibly the loading/rendering time of your notification.

Comment: Never mind that it will increase the weight. So do just 100x100 and give the drawables? Tell me why my icon extends from the top to the bottom of the strip.